# Como usar herança e polimorfismo ao passar um JSON para um Controller MVC C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Possuo um método MVC que recebe uma classe cliente como parâmetro:

```
      public async Task<ActionResult> Cadastrar(cliente model)
      {
      }
```

Acontece que essa classe tem dois filhos, uma classe chamada pessoa.
e outra classe chamada empresa que também herda de cliente.

Gostaria de saber se é possível (e como) eu faço para passar um JSON
genérico para esse método? podendo tanto ser um objeto **PESSOA** como um objeto **EMPRESA**. Um polimorfismo mesmo.

Já tentei passar objeto pessoa ou empresa e não deu certo. 
mas se coloco pessoa ou empresa no lugar de cliente e passo o JSON recebo
normalmente os dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente, usando um *Model Binder* escrito por você e um pouco de Reflection:

```
public class ClienteModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        var tipoString = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + ".Tipo");
        var tipo = Type.GetType(
            (string)tipoString.ConvertTo(typeof(string)), 
            true
        );

        var model = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, tipo);
        return model;
    }
}
```

No evento `Application_Start` do seu `Global.asax.cs`, registre seu *Model Binder*:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Cliente), new ClienteModelBinder());
}
```

No `form` ou no JSON, você precisará passar um campo `Tipo` para que o *Model Binder* saiba o que está sendo passado:

```
@Html.Hidden("Tipo", Model.GetType())
```

Ou:

```
{ 'Tipo': 'Pessoa' }
```

Ou ainda, você pode testar outra coisa. Por exemplo, se o valor passado tem definido um CPF ou CNPJ, ou ainda um nome ou uma razão social, aí não precisa de um campo `Tipo` no `form` ou no JSON:

```
var cpf = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + ".Cpf");
if (cpf != null) 
{ 
    /* É Pessoa Física */
    var model = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Pessoa));
    bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, typeof(Pessoa));
    return model;
}
```

Comment: valeu, testando aqui agora